# Seasonal Sub Series Plot in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm studying a seasonal monthly time series and I like to plot the Seasonal Sub Series Plot or a Box Plot by Month in SAS.
Somthing like the ones at the bottom of the page at the following link:

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc443.htm

I'm not sure how exactly to get this done in SAS. I appreciate any help.
SE

Comment: I'm running proc X11 for the seasonality and that gives me a matrix format table in which rows are labled by year from 2003 to 2013 and columns are labled by months from jan to dec. I tried proc transpose to change the place of rows and columns and then plot it, but I couldn't get it to work since proc transpose changed the names of the columns! Overal I haven't proceed that much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't speak to the seasonality, but box plots are pretty simple.  Assuming you create a SAS dataset from the data in that web site, try this:

```
proc format ;  
 value mn_name 1='January'
               2='February'
               3='March'
               4='April'
               5='May'
               6='June'
               7='July'
               8='August'
               9='September'
              10='October'
              11='November'
              12='December'
           other='Invalid';
run;
proc sort data=have;
   by month;
run;
proc boxplot data=have;
   plot Oscillation*month;
   format month mn_name.;
run;
```